# Set and check for empty var inside a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I created a make target which fetches a list of files from `git ls-files` and passes them to `phpcs`, a coding standards utility.

The problem is that I don't want to run it if no files are returned. (because it then tries to analyze the entire codebase)

```
phpcs:
    FS=$$(git ls-files -om --exclude-standard '*.php'); \
    vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php $$FS
```

How would I exit if `$FS` (which is set in the first line) is empty?

I'm running the default `gnu-make` which comes with OSX. (`3.8.1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a makefile question.  You are using shell commands to perform these operations so you have to come up with a shell solution for your problem: make doesn't enter into it.

You can do something like this:

```
phpcs:
        FS=$$(git ls-files -om --exclude-standard '*.php'); \
        test -z "$$FS" || vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php $$FS
```

PS. There's no such release as GNU make 3.8.1.  You mean, I assume, GNU make 3.81.

Comment: Understood, thanks for explaining. I confirmed this does in fact work. Also, you are correct... I meant GNU make `3.81`.